# PHP PhantomJS: JS not executed?

Tags: php, phantomjs

I want to retrieve a value from a website with PHP.
Most of the site seems to be loaded/displayed with JS.

Website: https://www.iconomi.net/dashboard/#/INDEX
Value: $0.9273

So I thought to get that value, I'd have to execute the JS, like a browser.

Using [PHP PhantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs) and [MTS (wrapper)](https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS) I tried this:

```
$myUrl = "https://www.iconomi.net/dashboard/#/INDEX";
$browser = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getBrowser('phantomjs');
$windowObj = $browser->getNewWindow($myUrl);
$domData = $windowObj->getDom();
echo $domData;
```

But it doesn't return the "dynamic site", just the static HTML.

I also tried without the wrapper, but

> $response->getContent();

also didn't return any dynamic content.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I had to add a delay (of ~3 seconds) between getNewWindow() and getDom().